# Terminal muestra la ejecución desordenada

Tags: python, macos, terminal, imprimir, ejecutar

Os pongo en contexto,
estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que creo una red social
1ª he elegido un nombre que realizo mediante prints que sería así:

```
print("te damos la bienveniada a...")
print("   _____                     ___.                  __ ")   
print("  /     \  __ __  ______ ____\_ |__   ____   ____ |  | __ ")
print(" /  \ /  \|  |  \/  ___// ___\| __ \ /  _ \ /  _ \|  |/ / ")
print("/    Y    \  |  /\___ \\  \___| \_\ (  <_> |  <_> )    < ")
print("\____|__  /____//____  >\___  >___  /\____/ \____/|__|_ \ ")
print ("        \/           \/     \/    \/                   \/ ")
```

pero cuando lo ejecuto en la terminal se imprime desordenado y no sé el porqué

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El carácter `\` tiene significado especial dentro de una cadena. Es un carácter "de escape". Esto significa que su significado depende de qué carácter venga después.

Por ejemplo, si despues viene una `n`, (es decir, tienes `\n`) la cadena resultante tendrá un retorno de carro en ese punto (un solo byte con el código del retorno de carro, en lugar de dos bytes con los códigos de `\` y  de `n`).

Si el código después de `\` no es uno de los que Python espera, entonces el `\` pierde su significado especial y significa simplemente el carácter `\`.

En tu cadena, al usar `\` como parte del ascii-art, puede darse el caso de que en algunos puntos actúe como carácter especial y en otros no. En particular tras el `\` en la mayoría de los lugares en que lo usas, suele haber un espacio. En ese caso no tiene significado especial y se ve bien. Pero hay un lugar en el que tras `\` aparece otro `\`. En ese caso sí actúa como código de escape y la secuencia `\\` se sustituye por un solo carácter (un solo `\` en este caso), lo que desalinea esa línea.

### Solución

Si quieres que una cadena python pueda contener `\` sin que tenga nunca significado especial, pon una `r` delante de las comillas que abren la cadena. Es decir, tu programa sería así:

```py
print(r"te damos la bienveniada a...")
print(r"   _____                     ___.                  __ ")
print(r"  /     \  __ __  ______ ____\_ |__   ____   ____ |  | __ ")
print(r" /  \ /  \|  |  \/  ___// ___\| __ \ /  _ \ /  _ \|  |/ / ")
print(r"/    Y    \  |  /\___ \\  \___| \_\ (  <_> |  <_> )    < ")
print(r"\____|__  /____//____  >\___  >___  /\____/ \____/|__|_ \ ")
print(r"        \/           \/     \/    \/                   \/ ")
```

## Bonus

Puedes instalar la biblioteca `pyfiglet` que es precisamente para crear este tipo de asciiart y te trae muchas "fuentes" (entre ellas la que estás usando). Se haría así:

```py
from pyfiglet import Figlet
font = Figlet(font="graffiti")

print(font.renderText("Muscbook"))
```

Y sale:

```
   _____                     ___.                  __
  /     \  __ __  ______ ____\_ |__   ____   ____ |  | __
 /  \ /  \|  |  \/  ___// ___\| __ \ /  _ \ /  _ \|  |/ /
/    Y    \  |  /\___ \\  \___| \_\ (  <_> |  <_> )    <
\____|__  /____//____  >\___  >___  /\____/ \____/|__|_ \
        \/           \/     \/    \/                   \/
```